# ocfs partition creation failure

Tags: filesystem, linux-headers, cluster

I am trying to create a cluster file system shared by two devices. I am seeing the following error:

```
mkfs.ocfs2 successful

mount.ocfs2: Cluster name is invalid while trying to join the group
 Stopping ocfs2 and o2cb on device side:
Warning: Permanently added '11.1.1.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Stopping o2cb (via systemctl): o2cb.service.
Unmounting ocfs2_dlmfs filesystem: OK
 Copying cluster.conf to device:
 Starting ocfs2 on device side:
Mounting ocfs2_dlmfs filesystem at /dlm: OK
Setting cluster stack "o2cb": OK
Starting O2CB cluster ngd: Failed
Cluster ngd created
Node In-Situ-machine2 added
o2cb_ctl: Internal logic failure while adding node node1
Stopping O2CB cluster ngd: OK
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/catalina24/’: Read-only file system
mount.ocfs2: Unable to access cluster service while trying to join the group
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem "mount.ocfs2: Cluster name is invalid while trying to join the group" is fixed when you use the next command:

```
o2cb register-cluster ocfs2
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Why is this not in their docs!!!!